# angular float number fraction down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

how get number with no fraction in angular in view with filter?
i mean like 1.777 
i want to output 1 (angular makes that 2)
how round float number down!
myvalue is 1.777
myvalue| number:0
the output will be 2 
how approach to 1?

something like parseInt in jquery i need in view????
is there filter in angular that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simply `{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}`

**Markup**

```
<h6>flight duration:   {{item.travelTime | number: 0}}</h6></div>
```

Look at [**Number filter API**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

**Update**

For making round number then you need to use `number` filter inside your custom filter.

**Markup**

```
<h6>flight duration:   {{item.travelTime | numberFormat: 0}}</h6></div>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('numberFormat', function($filter){
   return function(value, fractionSize){
      if(value){
         $filter('number')(Math.round(value), fractionSize)
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: no i need round float number down not up for example if 1.777 output is 2  and 1.444 output is 1 how i disable rounding ?  i need 1 the valid number

Comment: @mohsen for that you need to create your own custom filter

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui']).filter('parseInt', 
    function() {
        return function(input) {
            return parseInt(input);
        };
    }
);
```