# Issue With Angular Methamatical Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I got a problem with an arithmetic expression in angularjs

i.e

```
{{ (item.Price + (item.Price * item.Discount))/100 }}
```

I want this to calculate the total price of a product including it's discount.

Eg.:

Price: 200
Discount: 2%

Result should be 204. But it shows 2004. I don't know why it add up as string with the first price...

Any guesses...

Comment: What kind of discount is that, that gets added to the price? just sayin'

Comment: i want to show the actual price of thing before discount was this...

Comment: Try converting to Number - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478738/arithmetic-addition-is-not-working-in-ng-bind/32478904#32478904. The comments of the answer has what works / doesn't work in specific cases.

Comment: Isn't that the thing of a discount? Subtract it from the actual price? =)

Comment: can't you do this in your controller and just return the price after this?

Comment: Why are you dividing everything with 100?

Comment: The discount is in % and also the code is written inside ng-repeat so i can;t do it in controller

Comment: Exactly only the discount is in % not the whole product of your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as per your comment.

Just do this:

```
<p ng-repeat='obj in arr'>{{ item.priceb4disc(obj.price, obj.disc) }}</p>
```

you can calculate all the discount and price in the controller and set the result to the `$scope.item.priceb4disc` and show it in the dom:

```
  $scope.arr = [{"price":200, "disc":2},{"price":500, "disc":10}];
  $scope.item = {};
  $scope.item.priceb4disc = function(price, disc) {
     return (price + (price * disc/100));
  };
```

still i feel you don't need the last `/100`: [plnkr demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fr6ptdvRkUbi8LSrWq6I?p=preview)

Comment: but i am doing these things inside ng-repeat I think this won't work for multiple products

Comment: @KailashChandra Ohh! then you should add all this requirement and a sample demo to work with. Although you can use the plnkr i have created and can you update it as per your requirement?

Comment: `<span ng-bind="function(Item.price, Item.discount)"></span>` instead of the interpolation.

Comment: thanks @skubski binding it with a function works... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your controller (snippet in `CoffeeScript`)

```
for item in items
   item.calculatedPrice = item.price + (item.price * item.discount / 100)
```

and then in your html markup you can use inside your `ng-repeat`, `{{item.calculated_price}}`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
  {{((item.Price | number) + (item.Price * item.Discount) | number) /100}}
```

maybe your calculation give fraction result!
trace them seperately to give the last result!

as @VVK said : 
if you have problem you can create parseInt filter example: [angular float number fraction down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903318/angular-float-number-fraction-down)